# How do I set configuration using Gradle for build flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**Existing system (Maven)**

I have an Android project which has two modules: `app` and `api`.

Currently, I use Maven to build it, and I have a `configuration.properties` in the app `resources` directory which has properties in it such as `exampleProperty=${property}`

I use the command line for my various builds like so `mvn clean install -Dproperty=customString`, and this swaps out the correct property so that it is `exampleProperty=customString`.

This property is read from by both `app` and `api` modules - and works fine.

---

**New system (Gradle)**

The Question: **Can I use `defaultConfig` to set a property in my `configuration.properties` file?**

I'm trying to use the `defaultConfig` (and eventually `productFlavors`) to create a setup where the `build.gradle` swaps out the properties instead of using the command line.

I've tried a number of ways to make changes to the `gradle.properties` file from the `defaultConfig` closure in the `build.gradle` file like so:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.editconfigproperties"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        System.setProperty('exampleProperty', 'customString')
        project.properties['exampleProperty']='customString'
        extensions.add('exampleProperty', 'customString')
        ext.exampleProperty = 'customString'  // This one seems to work
    }
}
```

I think the last one adds it to the `gradle.properties` file, but I can't figure out how to make the `configuration.properties` file read from it (or if that's even possible). I tried setting `exampleProperty=@exampleProperty@` in the `configuration.properties' file, but to no avail.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: I didn't I'm afraid. Might look into it again tonight, will let you know if I find a way.